# asp mvc return form and additional parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, optional-parameters

I want to send to my controller, a form (t_prospect object) and an additional parameter, depending of the choice of the user.

So in fact, I have two forms in my page, the prospect form, who send to my controller an t_prospect object and an other that appear only if the user want ton send an email at the same time as creating the prospect entries .

I get my optional form, by means of an ajax call who return me inputs corresponding.
So it's not exactly two forms but one form with the content of one object and one optional parameter.

My controller action :

```
public ActionResult AjoutRapide()
    {
        List<string> listModel = new List<string>();

        foreach (var tMailModel in db.t_mail_modele)
        {
            listModel.Add(tMailModel.nom);
        }
        ViewBag.listModel = listModel;
        ViewBag.json = string.Empty;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AjoutRapide(t_prospect t_prospect, string param = "" )
    {
        List<string> listModel = new List<string>();

        foreach (var tMailModel in db.t_mail_modele)
        {
            listModel.Add(tMailModel.nom);
        }
        ViewBag.listModel = listModel;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (param != null)
            {
                t_mail mail = new t_mail();
                db.t_mail.Add(mail);
            }
            db.t_prospect.Add(t_prospect);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(t_prospect);
    }
```

I tried that :

```
**@using (Html.BeginForm("AjoutRapide", "MvcProspect", new { param = "formulaireRapide" }))**
{

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nom, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nom)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nom)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.adresse, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.adresse)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.adresse)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.telephone, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telephone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.telephone)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.mail, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.mail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mail)
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.siteWeb, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.siteWeb)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.siteWeb)
        </div>
    </div>
    <select id="ddl_model">
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.listModel)
        {
            <option>@item</option>
        }
    </select>
    <div id="formulaire_param"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

But no way to get back the value of my optional parameter that is a json.Stingify string create by a javascript function.

How can I had to my `Html.BeginForm()`  The value of my optional parameter ?

Comment: Can you not add the optional parameter to the `t_prospect` object and add to the form as a hidden field? You could then populate it as part of the ajax call and it would be submitted as part of the form.

Comment: I work with an ddmx I don't think that I can modify my class as I want.
But there is already ans association between t_prospect and t_mail .
Did you think that I can do anything with that ?

Comment: Do you mean _edmx_? You can add a property by using a partial class - see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281897/entity-framework-4-using-edmx-how-to-add-a-field-into-to-model-that-db-does-n)

Comment: Yes, Edmx. I had a property in a partial class file . But I don't see how I can get the value of my json string on my new 'parameter' field .
Because as I said before, the "second form" is generated and the parameter field is the json string of all inputs of my generates inputs

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Could you use javascript to get the json string from the 2nd form on form.submit and add it to the hidden field property?

Comment: Yes I did it, and I get as well my parameter field filled .
Thank's for all !

Comment: The form.on('submit') start his action to late but it will be fixed if you change the submit in onlcick event for the button submit